# During Update Perform For Each On Last Insert ID

Tags: mysql

I have a very simple procedure which performs an update on multiple rows.  Is their a way I can loop through the insert id of each updated row?

```
BEGIN
UPDATE testTable set testValue = 2 
where username = inputUser and flag = 1;

//for each update performed, insert LAST_INSERT_ID() into tableB
END
```

is this possible?  If so, can you lead me in the right direction?

Comment: If you're more specific, I can help you more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LAST_INSERT_ID only gives you one last id. You can do multiple inserts without a loop. You can use the output of SELECT query and insert to the desired table. You can do something like that:

```
BEGIN
    UPDATE testTable set testValue = 2 
    where username = inputUser and flag = 1;

    INSERT into tableB (column1, column2)
    SELECT column1, column2 FROM testTable
    WHERE username = inputUser and flag = 1;
END
```

For example:

```
User (username, password)
UserLoginLog (username, last_log_in_date)

INSERT INTO UserLogInLog (username, last_log_in_date)
SELECT username, NOW() 
FROM User 
WHERE username = "JohnDoe"
```